# Go report card run for local project/private git

Tags: go

I want to use the `go report` but my project is in private repo. is it possible ? or on local project (in my machine)

https://goreportcard.com/

I want to verify that I'm in the right way and I currently cannot remove the private restriction.

Comment: Use the [go meta linter](https://github.com/alecthomas/gometalinter) locally and / or during your CI build, goreportcard.com uses that too.

Comment: The source code is available on github, so you should be able to make it do whatever you want, as long as you don't care that it's running on the goreportcard.com domain name.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can achieve same results via running following file checkers and linters locally:

`gofmt
go_vet
gocyclo
golint 
ineffassign
license
misspell`

all of them can be run from command line.

if you want to have one tool I would recommend gometalinter. 
https://github.com/alecthomas/gometalinter

`go get -u github.com/alecthomas/gometalinter
gometalinter --install
gometalinter --deadline=90s --disable-all ... #other flags`

Comment: thanks , so how should I test it to simulate the go reports card?

Answer (score 2):

Here's how you install and get report locally or in private server:

1) Prerequisites (Before you run `goreportcard-cli`, it needs to install some dependencies)

```
$ go get -u golang.org/x/lint/golint

$ go get github.com/fzipp/gocyclo

$ go get -u github.com/client9/misspell/cmd/misspell

$ go get github.com/gordonklaus/ineffassign

#deprecated, a reported issue in goreportcard-cli to switch to use golangcli-lint instead
$ go get github.com/alecthomas/gometalinter
```

2) Now, Install `cli` and then run it within your project dir:

```
#get whole project (for demo purpose only) 
go get github.com/gojp/goreportcard/...
```

**Note**: In real environment, you may need to only instal `cli`

```
$ go get github.com/gojp/goreportcard/cmd/goreportcard-cli
```

3) Testing it: Go to the project (private repo or run it within your local project)

```
$ cd $GOPATH/src/github.com/gojp/goreportcard
$ goreportcard-cli
```

You should get something like this

```
❯ goreportcard-cli
Grade: A+ (98.9%)
Files: 403
Issues: 39
gofmt: 100%
go_vet: 99%
golint: 100%
gocyclo: 91%
ineffassign: 99%
license: 100%
misspell: 100%
```